# preimage of dense meager set in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $B$ is a closed subspace of $H$ and $T:B\rightarrow H$ is a bounded linear operator. If the range of $T$ is dense meager set in $H$, is the preimage of $T$ equal to $H$?

I think the answer is yes. Because $T^{-1}(R(T))$ must be a $B$, but $B$ cannot be meager by Baire category theorem, so it must contain a non-empty open set, but this means $B=H$. Is my reasoning correct?